# Add multiples dict into a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have multiples list of dictionaries like this:

```
list_of_dictionaries_1 = [{
 'a':1,
 'b':2
}, {
 'a':3,
 'b':4
}]

list_of_dictionaries_2 = [{
 'c':1,
 'd':2
}, {
 'c':3,
 'd':4
}]
```

And I want to add each element into a new dictionary.

```
new_dictionary = {
data: [{
 'a':1,
 'b':2
}, {
 'a':3,
 'b':4
}, {
 'c':1,
 'd':2
}, {
 'c':3,
 'd':4
}]
}
```

So I made this for each list of dictionaries:

```
for dictionary_ in list_of_dictionaries_1:
    new_dictionary['data'] = dictionary_
```

But this just return the last element in the list of dictionaries.

```
new_dictionary = {
   data:[{
   'c':3,
   'd':4
  }]
}
```

How can I add all de dictionaries in the new dictionary?

Comment: `new_dictionary` is not a dictionary

Comment: `new_dictionary` is an invalid set-literal.

Comment: Yes, sorry I haven't asked correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you could do it like this:

```
new_dictionary = {'data': []}
for elem in list_of_dictionaries_1 + list_of_dictionaries_2:
    new_dictionary['data'].append(elem)

print(new_dictionary)
```

Output:

```
{'data': [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'c': 1, 'd': 2}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4}]}
```

Comment: Note that this is not list comprehension at all, and it's entirely redundant to use a loop to append each item to a new list after you join the two lists. The joined list itself is what the OP needs already.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.chain` to merge the two lists:

```
from itertools import chain
new_dictionary = {'data': list(chain(list_of_dictionaries_1, list_of_dictionaries_2))}
```

`new_dictionary` becomes:

```
{'data': [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'c': 1, 'd': 2}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary structure looks inconsistent. But however, you can do the below to achieve what you are trying for.

```
list_of_dictionaries_1 = [{'a':1, 'b':2 }, {'a':3, 'b':4}]
list_of_dictionaries_2 = [{'c':1, 'd':2 }, {'c':3, 'd':4 }]
list_of_dictionaries_1.extend(list_of_dictionaries_2)
print(list_of_dictionaries_1)
```

Output:
    [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'c': 1, 'd': 2}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4}]